# NSURLSession with backgroundSessionConfiguration and multipart/form-data request

Tags: ios, multipartform-data, nsurlsession

I'm trying to upload a video file to transloadit.com using `NSURLSession` with `backgroundSessionConfiguration`. Request needs to be `multipart/form-data` with some parameters in the request body (API key, etc.). iOS allows background upload only from a file `uploadTaskWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest, fromFile fileURL: NSURL)` so I can't use just NSData of the file, so transloadit return `INVALID_FORM_DATA` response, since iOS does not respect parameters in the body of the request when uploading a file. Can I configure `multipart/form-data` request without data of video file inside or maybe there are some other solutions?

Edit 3/27/16

Thanks Rob, got it working after creating a temp file. Now I have a dictionary with "params" key in it and I'm getting some weird behavior when uploading it. Here I'm adding it to a `NSMutableData`:

```
body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"params\"\r\n\r\n")
body.appendString("test\r\n")
body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey)\"; filename=\"\(fileName)\"\r\n")
body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n")
body.appendData(fileData)
body.appendString("\r\n")
body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
```

`appendString` is a helper function that basically does `string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)`
Upload process turns into infinite loop. As soon as I change `params` to something else, upload is working without any problems. Ideally I need to send following dictionary within the request body:

```
let auth = ["auth": ["key": "****", "expires": ""]]
let notifyURL = ["notify_url": "http://callback_url"]
let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = ["params": [auth, notifyURL]]
```

Comment: Write the full contents of the multipart request HTTP body to a file, and then supply that to `uploadTaskWithRequest(fromFile:)`.